# ASP.NET MVC DropDownListFor with model of type List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I have a view with a model of type `List<string>` and I want to place a drop down list on the page that contains all strings from the list as items in the drop down. I am new to MVC, how would I accomplish this?

I tried this:

```
@model List<string>
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x)
```

but that threw an error.

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => yourInputVariable,Model)  should work

Answer (score 128, accepted):

To make a dropdown list you need two properties:

1. a property to which you will bind to (usually a scalar property of type integer or string)
2. a list of items containing two properties (one for the values and one for the text)

In your case you only have a list of string which cannot be exploited to create a usable drop down list.

While for number 2. you could have the value and the text be the same you need a property to bind to. You could use a weakly typed version of the helper:

```
@model List<string>
@Html.DropDownList(
    "Foo", 
    new SelectList(
        Model.Select(x => new { Value = x, Text = x }),
        "Value",
        "Text"
    )
)
```

where `Foo` will be the name of the ddl and used by the default model binder. So the generated markup might look something like this:

```
<select name="Foo" id="Foo">
    <option value="item 1">item 1</option>
    <option value="item 2">item 2</option>
    <option value="item 3">item 3</option>
    ...
</select>
```

This being said a far better view model for a drop down list is the following:

```
public class MyListModel
{
    public string SelectedItemId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
@model MyListModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedItemId,
    new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text")
)
```

and if you wanted to preselect some option in this list all you need to do is to set the `SelectedItemId` property of this view model to the corresponding `Value` of some element in the `Items` collection.

Comment: This isnt working, how do you get the value on on controllers Post... SelectedItemId and Items are both null.

Comment: Appreciate your help, just needed to perform some modifications because my approach is to display a `List` of `Lists` and have a selectedValue, the rest of that remains same as `DropDownList` HTML Helper.

Comment: Add the attribute "BindProperty" to SelectedItemId property to get the selected item value.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a List of type string that you want in a drop down list I do the following:

**EDIT:** Clarified, making it a fuller example.

```
public class ShipDirectory
{
    public string ShipDirectoryName { get; set; }
    public List<string> ShipNames { get; set; }
}

ShipDirectory myShipDirectory = new ShipDirectory()
{
    ShipDirectoryName = "Incomming Vessels",
    ShipNames = new List<string>(){"A", "A B"},
}

myShipDirectory.ShipNames.Add("Aunt Bessy");

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ShipNames, new SelectList(Model.ShipNames), "Select a Ship...", new { @style = "width:500px" })
```

Which gives a drop down list like so:

```
<select id="ShipNames" name="ShipNames" style="width:500px">
    <option value="">Select a Ship...</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>A B</option>
    <option>Aunt Bessy</option>
</select>
```

To get the value on a controllers post; if you are using a model (e.g. MyViewModel) that has the List of strings as a property, because you have specified x => x.ShipNames you simply have the method signature as (because it will be serialised/deserialsed within the model):

> public ActionResult MyActionName(MyViewModel model)

> Access the ShipNames value like so: model.ShipNames

If you just want to access the drop down list on post then the signature becomes:

> public ActionResult MyActionName(string ShipNames)

**EDIT:** In accordance with comments have clarified how to access the ShipNames property in the model collection parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure this works. for the post MyActionName(MyViewModel model), what property will the selected item be bound to.  ShipNames property contains the list of selectable values only.

Comment: This works great and is a lot simpler that the highest answer.  @RayLoveless After posting, your model should contain a property/value like "model.ShipNames = A".

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question was asked a long time ago, but I came here looking for answers and wasn't satisfied with anything I could find. I finally found the answer here:

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-dropdownlist-dropdownlistfor

To get the results from the form, use the FormCollection and then pull each individual value out by it's model name thus:

```
yourRecord.FieldName = Request.Form["FieldNameInModel"];
```

As far as I could tell it makes absolutely no difference what argument name you give to the FormCollection - use Request.Form["NameFromModel"] to retrieve it.

No, I did not dig down to see how th4e magic works under the covers. I just know it works...

I hope this helps somebody avoid the hours I spent trying different approaches before I got it working.