# DropDownList not getting selected - MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor, list.selectedvalue

I have the DropDownList in view as below,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RoleID, new { @class = "dropdownlistCustom" })
@Html.DropDownList("RoleID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RoleID, new { @class = "dropdownlistCustom" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleID)
```

Tried both `DropDownList` and `DropDownListFor`, both are not getting the correct `SelectedValue`.

From Controller, I am setting the `selectedValue` param (see Last parameter of SelectList()) .

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    UserDetail userDetail=db.UserDetails.Find(id);
    if(userDetail!=null)
    {
       ViewBag.RoleID = new SelectList(db.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleStatus == "A"), "RoleID", "RoleName", userdetail.RoleID);
       return View(userdetail);
    }
}
```

Model :

```
[Display(Name = "Name Of the Role")]
public int RoleID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("RoleID")]
public virtual Role Roles { get; set; }
```

Comment: in controller, are you fetching userdetail from db or creating a new object?

Comment: I am doing the editing (`[GET]` request to `Edit`)... ie. I am fetching the data. I done most debugging, and I am getting the correct value in `userdetail.RoleID`

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would encourage you **not to use ViewBag**, but view models to pass your select list (or data for select list) along from controllers to views.

Second of all, I would encourage you to look [at this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142961/mvc3-dropdownlistfor-a-simple-example) or [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688910/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlistfor-with-model-of-type-liststring) (preferably both) of `DropDownListFor` usage. I think you over-complicating `SelectList`. Less simple it is, less confused you will be as to why is it not working as expected. Just take existing example and change variable names to yours.

Another *big tip why not to use `ViewBag`* is that when you build your view model you can build a select list right there in the controller where you fetch your data from wherever. Then in the view you will only need to use pre-built view model property where `SelectList` argument is provided - cleaner and nicer. View should do least manipulations with data, but only to present it in the right format in the right way in the right place.

Just look at those examples I provided, I am sure you smart enough to figure it out how to use `DropDownListFor` properly, its very very easy, you just need to provide right parameters at the right places, see what others do and do the same.

Hope this helps, please keep me posted about your progress.

Comment: You can, its bad practice. Its like global variables in old days. It is easy to setup and start with, it bytes you back when you need to return to your code, from readability, maintainability perspective. Also not less improtant - its not strongly typed, which is another source of possible bugs. With View Model you have strongly typed properties that can be used for rendering select list, string[] or List<strings> for example, but can be anything. Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not using `DropDownListFor` correctly. The function definition you're after is:

```
DropDownListFor(lambda, selectList, *selectedItem*, htmlAttributes)
```

`RoleId` should be passed as the `selectedItem` parameter, so you're missing the `selectList` parameter. MVC doesn't create that for you automatically with `DropDownListFor`, you have to tell it what select list to use by either creating it inline, passing it into `ViewBag` or setting it on your model and specifying which property to use.

**EDIT**

Sorry. That's my bad. It's still early here and we lost an hour (daylight savings), so my brain is not all there yet. I mixed `DropDownListFor` and `DropDownList`. With `DropDownListFor`, the selected item comes from the set value on the model, but you still need to provide a proper `SelectList`. It appears you're trying to specify the selected item where you should be telling it what `SelectList` to use.

If you were to use `DropDownList`, then you would need to specify both the `SelectList` to use and the selected value.

Comment: but I can't find a overload which takes `selectedItem` param

Comment: I am setting the `SelectList` from the controller, you can see that in my Question, that Edit Action. Also I am setting the SelectedValue as correct value from there (last param)... when I am debugging I can see the correct value is set as selected, but unfortunatly I am not getting that in the View (I also debugged in View rendering area also)

Comment: It's probably because you're casting your `SelectList` into an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. That'll carry your items over, but not the selected value. Cast it as a true-blue `SelectList` and see if that doesn't fix it.