# Formatting a Drop Down List in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building an app with ASP.NET MVC 4. I'm binding my model to a view. In my view, I need a drop down list. That drop down list needs to show quarters. The quarters should be displayed as "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", and "Q4". My model, only has quarter numbers. They are defined like this:

```
public List<short> Quarters = new List<short>() { get; set; }
public short? SelectedQuarter = null;

public void Initialize() {
  Quarters.Add(1);
  Quarters.Add(2);
  Quarters.Add(3);
  Quarters.Add(4);
}
```

Somehow, I need to prepend "Q" to each value. However, I'm not sure how to do this in ASP.NET MVC. How does someone do this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC DropDownListFor with model of type List<string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688910/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlistfor-with-model-of-type-liststring)

Comment: You need to generate `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` for use by your dropown (e.g. `new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Q1" }` so you can bind to your model property `short SelectedQuarter`, but display the corresponding text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a SelectList to be used by `DropdownListFor()` so that you bind the selected option to property `SelectedQuarter`, but display the 'friendly' name.

View model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  [Display(Name = "Quarter")]
  [Required]
  public short? SelectedQuarter { get; set; } // must be a property, not a field!
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> QuarterList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
  MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
  ConfigureViewModel(model);
  return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Edit(MyViewModel model)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
  }
  // model.SelectedQuarter contains the selected value
}

private void ConfigureViewModel(model)
{
  model.SelectedQuarter = new List<SelectListItem>()
  {
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Q1" },
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Q2" },
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Q3" },
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Q4" },
  }
}
```

View

```
@model MyViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedQuarter)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedQuarter, Model.QuarterList, "-Please select-")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedQuarter)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this property:

```
public List<short> Quarters { get; set; }
```

Then in your view or any other consuming code you can generate a list of strings with something like:

```
model.Quarters.Select(q => "Q" + q)
```

or:

```
model.Quarters.Select(q => string.Format("Q{0}", q))
```

However, semantically it really feels like this belongs on a view model and not in consuming code.  Ideally the view should only ever need to bind directly to properties on the view model, not transform those properties.  Something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> QuartersDisplay
{
    get { return Quarters.Select(q => string.Format("Q{0}", q)); }
}
```

Then consuming code can just bind to that property:

```
model.QuartersDisplay
```

(If the model is a domain model then I'd recommend introducing a view model between the domain and the view, since this wouldn't belong on a domain model.)

---

Thinking about this a little more... Do you want *one* property with both the displays *and* the backing values for the drop down list?  That would likely be a `IDictionary<short, string>`, I imagine?  Something like this:

```
public IDictionary<short, string> QuartersOptions
{
    get { return Quarters.ToDictionary(q => q, q => string.Format("Q{0}", q)); }
}
```

In which case you'd bind to that property:

```
model.QuartersOptions
```

Keep in mind that a drop down list often binds to *two* things.  The property which holds the list of possible values (which is what we've built here) and the property which holds the *selected* value (which remains your `SelectedQuarter` property).