# MVC DropDown for model inside ViewModel

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, razor

Im working on an MVC application and for my current form I have a ViewModel like

```
public class MyViewModel
    {

        public MyModel MyModel { get; set; }
        ...
```

and MyModel has a type

```
public class MyModel 
    {

        public int MyModelTypeId { get; set; }
        ...
```

Now, i need a DropDownList to popuulate MyModelTypeId,

this is what I Have in the View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MyModelTypeId", String.Empty)
```

and in the Controller:

```
ViewBag.MyModelTypeId = new SelectList(db.MyModelTypes, "MyModelTypeId", "MyModelTypeName", model.MyModel.MyModelTypeId);
```

Now, the drop down is being populated well but, on post, the picked value is not being binded to 'MyModel'

What am I doing wrong

Comment: this will help for sure: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5688922/1638261

Comment: Because you generating a `<select name="MyModelTypeId" ... >` but you model does not contain a property named `MyModelTypeId` (but it does contain one named `MyModel.MyModelTypeId`). Always use the strongly typed HtmlHelpers - `DropDownListFor()`

Answer (score 2):

The dropdown list is being bound to the `MyModelTypeId` property you have created in the ViewBag, not the `MyModelTypeId` property of the `MyModel' class.

You should store the select list in MyModel

```
public class MyModel 
{
    public int MyModelTypeId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MyModelTypes { get; set; }
```

Assign the select list you create in your controller to this property, and then render the dropdown list in your view, passing the `MyModelTypeId` as the value to bind the selected item to, and `MyModelTypes` as the select list to use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyModel.MyModelTypeId, Model.MyModel.MyModelTypes)
```

When the form is submitted, the selected value will be bound to `MyModel.MyModelTypeId`