# MVC Dropdownlist, Get Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I need help with a project i'm doing for my employer but it was a really long time since i worked with MVC and im the only backend guy here and im an intern so heh..

When i want to create a Product. I need there to be a dropdownlist with a list of all Customers(maybe even ordered A - Z)

What am i doing wrong and what is it that i'm not seeing. My result so far is just that it types out the Object. I dont really know how to obtain the customer.Name without using a Foreach and that just ends up weird in the DropdownList

atm it looks something like this

```
@model Co56_Invoice_.Models.Collection
<h2>Skapa ny produkt</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Product</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                     @Html.DropDownList("Kunder", new SelectList(Model.customer), "Välj kund")
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
}
```

And the collection class is a list of Customers and Products

```
public class Collection
{
    public List<Customer> customer { get; set; }
    public List<Product> product { get; set; }
}
```

And heres my Create product Actions

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        col.customer = (from o in db.Customers select o).ToList();
        return View(col);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CustomerID,ProductID,Name,StartDate,Interval,Price,YearPrice,TotalPrice,Category,Paid")] Product product)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Products.Add(product);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e.InnerException;
        }

        return View(product);
    }
```

Comment: This is one way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688910/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlistfor-with-model-of-type-liststring

Comment: Past model as text value pair in for raor to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your List into a SelectList(). Try this

```
@Html.DropDownList("Kunder", Model.customer.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Name.ToString(), Value = x.CustomerId.ToString() }).ToList(), "Välj kund")
```

Comment: Do you know a proper way or a Stackflow thread about to get

    @Html.EditorFor("Produkt", Model.product.Select(x => x.Name))