# mvc Dropdown list with model of type list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I am pretty new to MVC however I have been trying to use a dropdownlist in a view  which has a model of type List<>.  The reason for this is to create multiple records on a single page.

I have been able to successfully create a view that is not of type List<> and a single record at a time, but in spite of a lot of googling can not implement the solution when I implement the view with a model of type List<>.

Model

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int VatRateID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("VatRateID")]
    public virtual VatRate VatRate { get; set; }

}
```

Controller

```
    // GET: /Product/Bulkdata
    public ActionResult BulkData()
    {
        PopulateVatRateDropDownList();
        List<Product> model = new List<Product>();
        model.Add(new Product
                        {
                            ProductID = 0,
                            Description = "",
                            VatRateID = 1
                        }
                );
        return View(model);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Product/Bulkdata

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult BulkData(
        [Bind(Include = "Description,VatRateID")]
        List<Product> products)
    {

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var p in products)
                {
                    db.Product.Add(p);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Bulk - Unable to save changes, Try again, and if the probelm persists contact your administrator");
        }
        PopulateVatRateDropDownList();
        return View(products);
    }

    private void PopulateVatRateDropDownList(object selectedVatRate = null)
    {
        var vatRateQuery = from v in db.VatRate
                           select v;
        ViewBag.VatRateID = new SelectList(vatRateQuery, "VatRateID", "VatRateDescription", selectedVatRate);
    }
```

View

```
   @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
   {
       int j = 0;
       foreach (var i in Model)
       {

            <tr style="border:1px solid black">
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[j].Description)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[j].Description)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownList("VatRateID", String.Empty)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[j].VatRateID)
                </td>
                <td>
                   @if (j > 0)
                   {
                        <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                   }
                </td>
            </tr>
            j++;
       }
   }
```

When I run the application with this code then 0 is always past back to vatRateID.  I have tried numerous other solution other than the above including
[ASP.NET MVC DropDownListFor with model of type List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688910/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlistfor-with-model-of-type-liststring).  As I have mentioned I am new to mvc so I know there is probably something simple that I am missing.  Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: And your use of `DropDownList()` does not make sense - its binding to `VatRateID` but you model is `List<Product>` and `List<T>` does not contain a property named `VatRateID`. You also excluding everything from binding by you use of the `[Bind]` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, could you please provide an example of how I should use DropDownList() in the above

Comment: You code does not make sense so I don't know what you trying to do but bess guess is `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].VatRateID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.VatRateList) .... }` and change the `ViewBag` property to `VatRateList` (it cannot be the same as the property your binding to). And remove the `[Bind]` attribute

Comment: Stephen,  thank you so much. It was he DropDownListFor that I was struggling with, I changed it to what you suggested above and changed the ViewBag propert to VatRateList - all working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Stephen in comments:

In the view, changed the foreach to a for loop as per the article in Stephen's comment and used DropdDownListFor

`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].VatRateID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.VatRateList)`

Also amended the controller to rename the ViewBag property to VatRateList

'
        private void PopulateVatRateDropDownList(object selectedVatRate = null)
        {
            var vatRateQuery = from v in db.VatRate
                               select v;
            ViewBag.VatRateID = new SelectList(vatRateQuery, "VatRateID", "VatRateDescription", selectedVatRate);
        }
'