# how to access different entities of different models in same controller and view in asp mvc5 using ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i want to show dropdown list in view of design and dropdown list items will be get from Title from brands model.

**Design model**

```
public class Design
{
    public int DesignId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Desciption { get; set; }
    public int? price { get; set; }
    public bool Isdeleted { get; set; }
    public string AddedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AddedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    //temp data 
    public string brandTitle { get; set; }
    //[MaxLength]
    public string pictureLocation { get; set; }
}
```

**Brand model**

```
public class Brand
{
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Isdeleted { get; set; }
    public string AddedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AddedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**controller of Design**

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
            return View();
    }
```

**create view of Design.**

```
@model E_Darzi.Models.Design

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.brandTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5688922/3082296

Answer (score 1):

access data in controller and send it to view

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    var data = db.DesignBrandsVM.Include(d=>d.Brand).ToList(); 
    returen view(data);
}
```

Save values into different entities
**create vm class**

```
public class DesignBrandsVM
    {
        public int DesignId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Desciption { get; set; }
        public int? price { get; set; }
        public bool Isdeleted { get; set; }
        public string AddedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AddedDate { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }


        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool Isdeleted { get; set; }
        public string AddedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AddedDate { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**
assign values in post method and save into db

```
    public ActionResult Create(DesignBrandsVM vm){
    var Design = new Design()
    {
        Title = vm.Title,
        Desciption = vm.Desciption,
        price = vm.price,
        Isdeleted = false
    };

    var Brand = new Brand()
    {
        Title = vm.BrandTitle,
        Isdeleted = false
    };

    db.Design.Add(Design);
    db.Brand.Add(Brand); 
    db.SaveChanges(); 
}
```