# Values selected in dropdown not being passed to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I followed [Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc) to populate a multi select dropdown from a method call, but the value I am selecting is not being passed to the controller.

```
<form asp-controller="ApiController" asp-action="Usage">
<label asp-for="Api"></label>
<div>
    <select id="api" class="form-control" asp-for="Api" asp-items="@Model.Api">

    </select>
</div>
</form>
```

The options in this dropdown contain all Apis.

**Model**

```
public class Model
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Api { get; set; }
}
```

When I look at the action method, the model has a `Null` value for Api.

Comment: Please include more of the cshtml file including at least your @model declaration and the form tag that contains this select control.  As is there is not enough context to answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC DropDownListFor with model of type List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688910/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlistfor-with-model-of-type-liststring)

Comment: @casey Added some more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `asp-for` tag holds the selected item and it should not be the same as the collection set in `asp-items`.
So add a new property, which matches the value type set of the SelectListItems of API(in this example a use an int), on the model like this

```
public class Model
{
    public int selectedApi { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Api { get; set; }
}
```

and use it on the select tag for the selected item

```
<select id="api" class="form-control" asp-for="selectedApi" asp-items="@Model.Api">
</select>
```

Comment: Made this change, but the value of both `selectedApi` and `Api` in the controller action are still `Null`.

Comment: Also, I cant really use this approach because changing `asp-for` to `SelectListItem ` changes my dropdown to a single select dropdown. I need it to be a multi select dropdown.

Comment: @JoshMuroe u still need the Api  values in the model. Updated the answers model. Have you linked the *@model* to the page

Comment: Yes, I still have the `List<SelectListItem> Api` in there. The model is linked to the page since I have other input fields on the page and they are passed to the controller action just fine.

Comment: @JoshMuroe you need to set the selected item to the value type of the SelectListItem value. Updated the answer