# How to create a dropdownlist in C# ASP.NET MVC web application w/SQL backend using docker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

This is the class:

```
public class Book
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorFirstName { get; set; }
    public string AuthorLastName { get; set; }
    public List<Author> Authors_List { get; set; }
}
```

CSHTML:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AuthorId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AuthorId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @*@Html.DropDownList("AuthorId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-contol"})*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuthorId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I just don't understand how to return the authorList as a dropdown

Comment: What does Docker have to do with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC DropDownListFor with model of type List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688910/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlistfor-with-model-of-type-liststring)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688910/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlistfor-with-model-of-type-liststring for a similar example. Note that you will need to pull an 'id' and a 'display value' out of your `author` object list items to properly build your drop down list